# Problems when linking with boost 1.60

Tags: c++, boost, linker, cmake

I have a project using boost 1.60. Currently, the build of this project fails with the following message:

```
libboost_thread-vc140-mt-1_60.lib(thread.obj) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
```

This should be easy to solve, but it's a strange message. So I verified that the boost libraries were really `x64` with `dumpbin`. Specially, I checked  `libboost_thread-vc140-mt-1_60.lib` and got the result, `8664 machine (x64)`.

My next assumption was that `CMake` was doing something wrong. Dumping out some variables yielded the following:

```
-- BOOST_ROOT: D:\path\to\project\..\ext/boost
-- BOOST_LIBRARYDIR: D:\path\to\project\..\ext/boost/lib64
-- BOOST_INCLUDEDIR: D:\path\to\project\..\ext/boost/include
-- Boost version: 1.60.0
```

These are all valid paths. Also, this section of `CMakeLists.txt` seems to be valid:

```
if(WIN32)
    # set boost needed boost library parameters
    set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
    set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
    set(BOOST_ROOT ${LIB_BOOST_ROOT_DIR})
    set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR ${LIB_BOOST_ROOT_DIR}/lib${LIB_SUFFIX})
    set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR ${LIB_BOOST_ROOT_DIR}/include)
    message("-- Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED: ${Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED}")
    message("-- Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS: ${Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS}")
    message("-- BOOST_ROOT: ${BOOST_ROOT}")
    message("-- BOOST_LIBRARYDIR: ${BOOST_LIBRARYDIR}")
    message("-- BOOST_INCLUDEDIR: ${BOOST_INCLUDEDIR}")
    find_package(BOOST 1.60 REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread system chrono regex filesystem iostreams log)
endif(WIN32)
```

So, what I am missing here?

**EDIT**

The build of the project is done with `ninja`. When I look at the `CMakeCache.txt`, I see this:

```
//Flags used by the linker.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING= /machine:x64
```

**EDIT 2**

And I looked into the build script. Before calling CMake, I start `vcvarsall.bat` with parameter `amd64`.

Comment: What architecture is your program set to build for? x86 or x64?

Comment: @ColinBasnett: I edited the question. You can see, that the build is set for x64.

Comment: Make sure the correct Visual Studio toolchain is set in your PATH during compilation of both the boost libraries and your program. This means that you should run all your commands from the x64 VS Command Line if you are targeting x64.

Answer (score 0):

From the message, you are certainly trying to link a 32 bit thing to a 64 bit thing. No question about it.

So, something is not what it seems to be.

Try getting the command line that is being run and running it yourself in a command prompt. Check all the paths and environment variables.